# Javascript slide up/roll up ad

Tags: javascript

Anyone know where I can find sameple coding for a jscript that slides an ad up from the bottom right of a screen. Like the slide up instant message ads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery and look at `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` functions:
http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/